# Trying to install (Or just try) Ubuntu, but i just get black screen immidiately after selecting "Install Ubuntu" in the first boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I am trying to boot from a USB drive prepaired with "UNetbootin" but after selecting "Install Ubuntu" the USB keeps flashing (Indikator LED) for a few seconds and then it stops. And then nothing. I have tried with Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon and i get the exact same problem there.. I have tried following this guide (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842) but with no luck. When the black screen comes I can take no action other than killing it on the power bottom (No "crtl-alt-del", "esc", "random smashing on the keyboard" is doing anything)

Answer (score 0):

Some systems aren't compatible with Ubuntu.

If you can tell me the **make and model** of you computer, and the **version of Ubuntu** you're trying to install, I could help you find out if you system is able to work with Ubuntu.

Also it would be very useful if you could tell me what OS you're installing Ubuntu **from**.

Good luck.

Comment: My computer is a Asus n73SV and im currently running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4.